# How to use keybase's git inside docker?

Tags: git, docker, keybase

I have a keybase client running in the machine, but I want to be able to push commits from inside the container. However, keybase works a little different than git itself. It provides a git 'url' like this: `keybase://private/user/project_name`.

I don't know which protocol it uses, but git is able to reach the keybase client on my machine, which encrypts everything and sends to the keybase cloud.

Answer (score 1):

As described in  "[Keybase launches encrypted git](https://keybase.io/blog/encrypted-git-for-everyone)", a git clone with such an URL works because a [remote helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote-helpers) is used:

[`keybase/client/go/kbfs/kbfsgit`](https://github.com/keybase/client/tree/master/go/kbfs/kbfsgit/)

> Keybase's remote helper performs all the crypto while letting git do its thing.

Comment: Thanks. But maybe it's possible to pass something to inside docker. Some file for example. Even X11 can be passed by a file to inside docker.

Comment: @LucasZanella Some file to represent what? I menat to answer your original question "I don't know which protocol it uses," This is done because of a remote helper calling a  `git remote-<transport>` (here  `git remote-keybase`)

Comment: @LucasZanella That means your Docker image must include that remote helper, as well as other keybase files. See as an example https://github.com/keybase/client/blob/master/packaging/linux/docker/node/Dockerfile